# how to add cache and browser cache in angular 4 app

Tags: angular

Can anyone can tell me how to add browser cache and cache storage like, assets items (Css files, Fonts, Images as well) in an angular 4 app?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this plugin.This library depends on Angular v4.0.0
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-cache/platform-browser#examples

Comment: actually i am not able to check angular 4 app performance.like page speed, cache, optimization,etc...

Comment: can u tell me how to use and where i can put change detection strategy on push using angular app i mean better option is (component or container)

Answer (score 0):

My mind keeps telling me that you should research Service Workers. Maybe using those you can achieve caching.

Comment: actually i am not able to check angular 4 app performance.like page speed, cache, optimization,etc... can u tell me any tool or any option